# Does Solana have a strategy for erasing immoral (and illegal) metadata?

Tags: nft, metadata, smart-contract

For instance, if someone uploaded (FBI level) bad (immoral, illegal, etc.) stuff into the metadata of an NFT, are there any moderation pools that are capable of erasing the metadata?  Or is that metadata essentially distributed to every blockchain node, without any sort of mitigation?

(Clean) Metadata for example purposes:  https://solscan.io/token/J7W8hKLg9a8KUsZu5wmMo6pufocW9qhRUR7Fx7isRoYU#metadata

---

Also, does anyone know of a (non-privacy) Solana fork that doesn't have NFTs, Smart contracts or any other sort of potential locations for people to upload smut?

The fact is BTC is almost kid friendly, but UTXOs, PoW, Mining, etc. is the opposite of climate friendly.

I find it tough to get involved with Solana given that full nodes might potentially have unfilterable bad stuff.

Like seriously... where's the climate & kid friendly calculator money?  I just want send tx's that been signed offline, haha.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding adult images as NFT metadata... there is not much you can do there. But to be fair, you can also get emailed an adult image.

Comment: From what I've learned so far, Nano definitely seems rather clean.

Comment: Not about to forward a spam email to everyone in my contact book though haha.

Answer (score 1):

**Images, videos, etc. are not typically stored on Solana**.

While the other answer is technically correct in that anyone can put any data values into a Solana account, Solana's storage (ie it's accounts) are optimised for data rather than storage. [The NFT metadata you mentioned](https://solscan.io/token/J7W8hKLg9a8KUsZu5wmMo6pufocW9qhRUR7Fx7isRoYU#metadata) points to an [IPFS URL where the image is actually stored](https://bafybeiav2mcyybjuqub5yxxc6hqkpfadjy4243q4qisu775dcum2ul3c5e.ipfs.nftstorage.link/14998.png).

Storage chains typically used for NFT images (or videos or 3D objects) are:

- Arweave
- IPFS
- Other permanent solutions

You can read about [Arweave's thoughts on managing illicit and / or morally wrong content](https://github.com/ArweaveTeam/arweave/issues/107).

Comment: I know how to read the metadata.  An answer is "forensic nodes" that have everything and "community nodes" that only need transactional data, and thus can be filtered by off chain regulators.   For example, NFT metadata aside from ownership records could be deleted.  As well, some smart contracts could possibly be voided and thusly erased entirely from "community nodes" where then you'd have to ask forensic nodes to verify historic smart contract transactions.  However, one problem with that is the concept of time capsule smart contracts that do something at a later block...

Comment: My point in showing the metadata was merely to imply this is more an IPFS / Arweave question than a Solana one and point to resources where you can find the policies. CSA material is generally much larger and the costs to store it on chain would be unreasonable.